# gtest more than three tests in one case

Tags: googletest

I am new to C++ and gtest. I have a case with 29 tests, and I would like to execute them all at once. But it seems gtest only process up to 3 tests at a time, it shows:

```
[==========] Running 29 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 29 tests from StringTests
[ RUN      ] StringTests.DelimitedStringComponent
[       OK ] StringTests.DelimitedStringComponent (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] StringTests.boolToString
[       OK ] StringTests.boolToString (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] StringTests.checkFixSASNull
[       OK ] StringTests.checkFixSASNull (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] StringTests.doubleToString
```

Then, stopped. What is wrong with it?

Comment: It looks like it started the 4th test then crashed before finishing it.  The crash could be a segfault or an unhandled exception.  If you want more help, you'll need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Does it crash or does it stops giving output?

In first case, crashing, it may be a crash in the tested code. For example, any assert will kill the proccess instantly. It will NOT be caught by gtest.

In case it simply stops giving output it may be an infinite loop or heavy calculus. Odds are  it is still calculating. In my case, adding several SCOPED_TRACE slows the tests by one or two order of magnitude. Also some of the tested operations may be slow and it can take several seconds or even minutes in finishing the test.

We will need more data to catch your exact problem. Hope it helps!